# Python - How to remotely execute processes in parallel and retrieve their output

Tags: python, ssh, subprocess, popen

I'm trying to remotely execute a command on an unknown number of hosts (could be anywhere from one host to hundreds) in a Python script. The simple way of doing this is the following, but obviously it can get ridiculously time-consuming with many hosts:

```
listOfOutputs = []
for host in listOfHosts:
  output = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split("ssh %s '<command>'" % host), stdout = subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
  listOfOutputs.append(output)
```

Is there a way to do this same thing, but have the commands remotely execute in parallel so it doesn't take as long?

Answer (score 2):

You have to run your `Popen.subprocess` calls each in a separate thread so you can launch as many as you want without blocking your main program.

I made a small example creating as many threads as there will be hosts. No big deal since threads will mostly wait for host reply (else, thread pools would have been better)

In my example, I have 3 hosts, and I perform a `ping` on each one. Outputs are stored in a thread-safe list of outputs and printed in the end:

```
import threading
import subprocess

listOfOutputs=[]

lock = threading.Lock()

def run_command(args):
    p = subprocess.Popen(["ping","-n","1",args],stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
    output,err = p.communicate()
    lock.acquire()  # listOfOutputs is thread-safe now
    listOfOutputs.append(args+": "+output)
    lock.release()

threads=[]
listOfHosts = ['host1','host2','host3']
for host in listOfHosts:
    t = threading.Thread(target=run_command,args=[host])
    t.start()          # start in background
    threads.append(t)  # store thread object for future join operation


for t in threads:
   t.join()  # wait for all threads to finish

# print results
for o in listOfOutputs:
    print(o)
    print("-"*50)
```